# Can I retrive the data with its nested data in object form in React from firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

problem: I want to retrive all collections in JhonDoe with its nested collection and/or docs in object or array of objects format.

Database in firestore:

```
--- members (collection)
         |
         --- JhonDoe (documents)
              |
              --- May (collection)
                    |
                    --- 28 (documents)
                          |
                          --- expense: "1"
                          |
                          --- gain: "2"
                          |
                          --- name: "Jhon Doe"
```

I want an object or array of objects like:

```
{
   May: {
         28: {
                 expense: '1',
                 gain: '2',
                 name: 'Jhon Doe'
             }        
         },
  //June: { } 
 }
```

What I have tried:

```
export const getMembersDailyGains = async (name) => {
  const dbName = name.replace(/\s/g, "");
  const gainsList = [];
  try {
    db.collection(`members/${dbName}`).get.then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        gainsList.push(doc.data());
        console.log(gainsList);  //error logged is below
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return gainsList;
};
```

The error logged:
error: FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but members/JhonDoe has 2.

changes:

```
 try {
    await db
      .collection("members")
      .doc(`${dbName}`)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
          gainsList.push(doc.data());
          console.log(gainsList);
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");  //this is being consoled
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(gainsList);
  return gainsList;
};
```

'No such document' is being consoled
I have consoled gainList in React component and it says pending promise.

Thank you for helping!

I am now using realtime database as I could not correct it

```
//set members' daily gains
export const setMembersDailyGains = async (name, gain, expense, date) => {
  const dbName = name.replace(/\s/g, "");
  const memberGainsRef = database.ref(`dailyGains/${dbName}/${date}`);
  const gainObj = {
    date: date,
    gain: gain,
    expense: expense,
  };
  await memberGainsRef.push(gainObj);
};


//get members' daily gains
export const getMembersDailyGains = (name) => {
  const dbName = name.replace(/\s/g, "");
  const memberGainsRef = database.ref(`dailyGains/${dbName}`);
  const gainsList = [];
  try {
    memberGainsRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        childSnapshot.forEach(function (cchildSnapshot) {
          cchildSnapshot.forEach(function (ccchildSnapshot) {
            const item = ccchildSnapshot.val();
            item.key = ccchildSnapshot.key;
            gainsList.push(item);
          });
        });
      });
      console.log(gainsList);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(gainsList);
  return gainsList;
};
```

I still want to use firestore.

Comment: In short, the answer is yes, however, StackOverflow isn't for having your code written for you. What have you tried so far? What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: Your current syntax error is ```db.collection(`members/${dbName}`).get``` but it should be ```db.doc(`members/${dbName}`).get()```.

Comment: Have you tried `.doc('${dbName}')` instead of  ```.doc(`${dbName}`)```?

Comment: It should be a string with the name of the member ('JhonDoe' in this case).

Comment: `${dbName}` and `'JohnDoe'` is same.

Comment: Try `db.document("members/$dbName").get().then...`

Comment: `$dbName` is the same as `${dbName}` and should change dynamically with the value of the `dbName` variable. What is the error with the suggestion of my last comment? And using `.doc(dbName)` instead?

Comment: Sorry! my mistake but same error.
FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but members/JhonDoe has 2.

Comment: Check that I changed `db.collection()` with `db.document()`. Did you also change it?